# How move codebuild artifact to s3 root

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend, aws-codebuild

I want to build my angular app and use s3 bucket as static website to host it.

My buildspec is:

```
version: 0.2

env:
  exported-variables:
    - S3_BUCKET
  variables:
    CACHE_CONTROL: "86400"
    BUILD_FOLDER: "dist"

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 18
    commands:
      - node -v
      - npm install -g @angular/cli@16.1.2
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm install
      - echo "{\"hash\":\"$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION\"}" > src/assets/commit-hash.json
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Building...
      - ng build --configuration production
      # - echo "User-agent\: \*\nDisallow: \/" > src/assets/commit-hash.json
  post_build:
    commands:
      - aws s3 sync ${BUILD_FOLDER} s3://${S3_BUCKET} --delete
      - echo S3 bucket is cleared.

artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
  discard-path: no
  base-directory: ${BUILD_FOLDER}
```

CodeBuild Artifacts config:

[image]

But as result I getting:

[image]

As you can see my build result in the directory with repo name...

What I doing wrong? How I can send a result of the build to s3 root?

Comment: Honestly, for this I wouldn't use the build artifact feature. I would just modify that `aws s3 sync` command you already have in the `post-build` phase to push your files to the bucket. And according to the documentation for the way `--delete` works, it should already be copying the files for you perfectly. That command doesn't "clear" the bucket, it copies all your files in the local folder to the S3 bucket, and deletes the files in the bucket that no longer exist in the local folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the place!!!

[image]

My angular config contain it in "outputPath". O M G